# Android - One class used by multiple activities

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity

I have a class that manages the data that was loaded from a file. This class is initialized in the main Activity. When the main Activity creates a new Activity the new Activity needs the data from the file, in other words, it needs a reference to the class that manages the data. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a class simply represents a chunk of data that it reads from a file, there's nothing wrong with making your class a singleton, like this:

```
class FileData {
    private static final FileData instance = readFile();
    public static FileData getInstance() {
         return instance;
    }
    private static readFile() {
        ... // Read the file, and create FileData from it
    }
    public int getImportantNumber() {
        return ...
    }
}
```

Now you can reference the data from all your other classes, like this:

```
FileData.getInstance().getImportantNumber();
```

Comment: I added 

`if(_instance == null)
    _instance = new FileData();`

to `getInstance()` so it will instantiate just once.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the best way is to create only one `instance` of your class. It's the **Singleton** design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The `singleton` pattern should suit your needs. This basically is a class that can only be instantiated once and manages that instance itself, so you can get it from anywhere.

A tutorial like this will help you get started: http://portabledroid.wordpress.com/2012/05/04/singletons-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

1.: Singleton pattern
2.: You could make the class Parcelable.

```
// simple class that just has one member property as an example
public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
private int mData;

/* everything below here is for implementing Parcelable */

// 99.9% of the time you can just ignore this
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

// write your object's data to the passed-in Parcel
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeInt(mData);
}

// this is used to regenerate your object. All Parcelables must have a CREATOR that implements these two methods
public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
    public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new MyParcelable(in);
    }

    public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
        return new MyParcelable[size];
    }
};

// example constructor that takes a Parcel and gives you an object populated with it's values
private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
    mData = in.readInt();
}
```

}

Then you are able to send your object through the intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("name_of_extra", myParcelableObject);
```

And get it in your 2nd Activity like that:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
MyParcelable myParcelableObject = (MyParcelable) i.getParcelableExtra("name_of_extra");
```

For convenience I took the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents) SO thread because it's pretty good, but it is also pretty basic though. You could even send Lists of objects trough Intents with it, but that is a little bit more complicated and would need way more example code and explaination. If thats your objective, please ask. For one object the code is totally fine though.